# .NET Standard portable library error with DescriptionAttribute

Tags: c#, attributes, .net-core, compatibility, .net-standard

I created a `.NET Standard` library that contains models that will be shared between `.NET Framework` apps and `.NET Core` apps.

I have an `enum` that uses `DescriptionAttribute`. Here's the enum that is inside the `.NET Standard 1.5` library:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public enum Foo
{
    [Description("Description A")]
    A,
    [Description("Description B")]
    B
}
```

To be able to use the `DescriptionAttribute`, I added `System.ComponentModel.Primitives` form a NuGet package.

Now in my .NET Framework app, I want to retrieve the description of the enum.

The implementation to get the description of the `enum` is different between `.NET Core` and `.NET Framework`. So in my `.NET Framework 4.6.2` app, I have an extension `GetDescription` that resolves the description attribute of the `enum` and returns it like that:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attr =
                   Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                     typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attr != null)
            {
                return attr.Description;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get that error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

[image]

I tried to add the `System.ComponentModel.Primitives` and I still have the error.

**EDIT**

Here's my project's structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the complete set of assemblies needed to load .NET Standard <= 1.6 libraries you should install the `NETStandard.Library` NuGet package along with any other package that the library references if you are using a `packages.config` based .NET Framework project.

In some cases, similar errors can be fixed by telling msbuild to update the built assembly's `.config`file during build to include binding redirects by adding the following snippet in the csproj file. This is usually needed when a library references a .NET Standard project and is loaded by a hosting application that doesn't. (e.g. classic unit test projects):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your case however (.NET Framework console app referencing a .NET Standard library) this should not be necessary if you install all needed NuGet packages. Your `app.config` file should automatically contain the necessary redirects.

Note that in VS 2017 15.3 this is going to change and you no longer need to reference the NuGet packages to add the necessary compatibility libraries to the build output.

Comment: I edited my question btw. By adding the `NETStandard.Library` in both `.NET Framework` apps, I'm getting that error now: `System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.`

Comment: Was `System.Runtime` installed as well? When I just tried it, it was installed as a dependency of `NETStandard.Library` and added a binding redirect to the `App.config` file and added a dll to the build output.

Comment: It's not present in my console app. However it was added automatically in .NET Framework app when I added `NETStandard.Library`

Comment: When I try to add it through the Nuget Manager, it says it's already installed, but I don't see it in the references...

Comment: :( try uninstall, and install again. sometimes it helps to re-open VS. Note that in the next VS 2017 update, the needed libraries will be added automatically. Just tired it using the VS 2017 15.3 preview 7.0 and it worked in a .NET Framework Console App without adding any NuGet packages.

Comment: And btw I'm using vs 2017. I had a lot of problems. I had to add Legacy2CPSWorkaround.

Comment: I already tried to uninstall/install. Reopen vs... It's a nightmare :(

Comment: I think I misunderstood your reference graph. did you add both nuget packages to both of the .net framework projects?

Comment: At first only on the console app. Then I added it to both